# Bootstrap-Table - Set specific background-color based on cell value

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap-table and I would like to color certain columns red or green based on the value that they are having.

I am having the following table:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<h2>Products</h2>
<div class="table-responsive">

  <table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-height="460" data-page-size="10" data-pagination="true" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-field="trx_date" scope="col">Transaction Date</th>
        <th data-field="order_type" scope="col">Buy/Sell</th>
        <th data-field="total_trx" scope="col">Total Transaction</th>
        <th data-field="SecInfo" scope="col">Details</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Sell</td>
        <td>$95,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Purchase</td>
        <td>$95,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Purchase</td>
        <td>$95,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Purchase</td>
        <td>$95,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Sell</td>
        <td>$95,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Sell</td>
        <td>$95,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Purchase</td>
        <td>$95,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Purchase</td>
        <td>$95,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Sell</td>
        <td>$95,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Sell</td>
        <td>$95,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Sell</td>
        <td>$95,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Is there a way to style each row like the following:

[image]

I tried to set a `data-element` on my `tr`-tag however, as I have many tables that need to get styled ist there an easier way with css?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is this What you need?**

The **reason for using class instead of manually telling to check `'nth'` cell** is because, May be in future **the order column in table** or **the number of column in the table may vary**, so its recommenced to use a selector to implement this

```js
$('.trans').each(function() {
  if (parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/\$|,/g, '')) <= 100000000.00) {
    $(this).parent().css({
      'background-color': '#89e289'
    })
  } else {
    $(this).parent().css({
      'background-color': '#f08080'
    })
  }

});
//If you want to check Sell/Product cell do:

$('.sales').each(function(){
  if($(this).text() == 'Sell'){
    $(this).parent().css({'background-color' : '#89e289'})
  }
  else{
     $(this).parent().css({'background-color' : '#f08080'})
  }
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<h2>Products</h2>
<div class="table-responsive">

  <table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-height="460" data-page-size="10" data-pagination="true" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-field="trx_date" scope="col">Transaction Date</th>
        <th data-field="order_type" scope="col">Buy/Sell</th>
        <th data-field="total_trx" scope="col">Total Transaction</th>
        <th data-field="SecInfo" scope="col">Details</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td class="sales">Sell</td>
        <td class="trans">$195,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td class="sales">Purchase</td>
        <td class="trans">$95,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td class="sales">Purchase</td>
        <td class="trans">$95,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td class="sales">Purchase</td>
        <td class="trans">$95,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td class="sales">Sell</td>
        <td class="trans">$195,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td class="sales">Sell</td>
        <td class="trans">$195,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td class="sales">Purchase</td>
        <td class="trans">$95,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td class="sales">Purchase</td>
        <td class="trans">$95,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td class="sales">Sell</td>
        <td class="trans">$195,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td class="sales">Sell</td>
        <td class="trans">$195,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td class="sales">Sell</td>
        <td class="trans">$195,001,513.81</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With your current HTML, you could use something like this to get the value of the appropriate cell, reformat the string into a float, and change the background color based on this value.

```
$('#table tr').each(function () {
    let value = this.children[2].innerHTML;
    
    // omit dollar signs and commas with replace and return a float
    value = parseFloat(value.replace(/\$|,/g, ''));
    
    // compare values and adjust styling
    value > 90000000.50 ? this.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen' : '';
    value < 10000000.75 ? this.style.backgroundColor = 'salmon' : '';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot set base color or styles of any elements in your HTML, depending on the content they have with CSS. This is something you must look over with javascript.

Why this? Because CSS is a frontend styling "modifier", that edits property of HTML without looking at its content and what there is written. It simply applies styles. With JavaScript however, you can edit the content by taking it, analyzing it, and changing its style.

I took your code and edited a little the content of it to modify and show you how you can deal with this in javascript. You can do that in more efficient ways but I went for simplicity and the DOM to make you understand at best

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    let price = document.getElementsByClassName('price')[i].innerText;
    console.log(price)
    if (price <= 100){  
        document.getElementsByClassName('price')[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    } else if (price > 100) {  
        document.getElementsByClassName('price')[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<h2>Products</h2>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-height="460" data-page-size="10" data-pagination="true" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-field="trx_date" scope="col">Transaction Date</th>
        <th data-field="order_type" scope="col">Buy/Sell</th>
        <th data-field="total_trx" scope="col">Total Transaction</th>
        <th data-field="SecInfo" scope="col">Details</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Sell</td>
        <td class="price">80</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Purchase</td>
        <td class="price">90</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Purchase</td>
        <td class="price">700</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Purchase</td>
        <td class="price">900</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Sell</td>
        <td class="price">500</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Sell</td>
        <td class="price">200</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Purchase</td>
        <td class="price">300</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Purchase</td>
        <td class="price">100</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Sell</td>
        <td class="price">100</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Sell</td>
        <td class="price">100</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8/18/2016</th>
        <td>Sell</td>
        <td class="price">100</td>
        <td><a href="">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```